# Android XML background sizes adapted for all screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Suppose if you have a `Layout` something like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mylayout" >

 //Other view elements like buttons, TextViews

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then you can dynamically change the `background` of the `layout` using below code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylayout);
        int images[] = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4};

        relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(images[getRandomNumber()]);
    }


    private int getRandomNumber() {
        //Note that general syntax is Random().nextInt(n)
        //It results in range 0-4
        //So it should be equal to number of images in images[] array
        return new Random().nextInt(4);
    }



}
```

how can i `automatically` adapt my background to the screen size of the device?

Comment: set the widhth and height attribute to match parent and it will adapt automatically

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this to your code to adjust the background to any screen.

```
relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using FillParent for Ralative layout you don't need to do anything extra to adapt screen size.
Your drawable will be stretched to fit screen.

Comment: Well what i want to do with my xml is that there is relative layout above (image) and linear layout below(buttons) see [Image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tqadw.png)